# T-SQL Query with XML PATH produces repeating parent nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Suppose I have 2 tables called tb1 and tb2

```
create table tb1
(
  id int

);
insert into tb1 values(100),(200);

create table tb2
(
  id int,
  col2 int
);

insert into tb2 values(100,1),(100,2),(100,3),(200,3),(200,4);
```

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
  t.id as [@healthAccountRecord]
,(
  SELECT t2.col2 as [DiagnosisCode/@code]     
  FROM dbo.tb2 as t2 
  WHERE t.id = t2.id    
  FOR XML PATH('DiagnosisCodes'), TYPE
)
 FROM dbo.tb1 as t
 FOR XML PATH('Account'), ROOT ('Accounts')
```

Here is my output:

```
<Accounts><Account healthAccountRecord="100"><DiagnosisCodes><DiagnosisCode code="1"/> 
</DiagnosisCodes><DiagnosisCodes><DiagnosisCode code="2"/></DiagnosisCodes><DiagnosisCodes> 
<DiagnosisCode code="3"/></DiagnosisCodes></Account><Account healthAccountRecord="200"> 
<DiagnosisCodes><DiagnosisCode code="3"/></DiagnosisCodes><DiagnosisCodes><DiagnosisCode code="4"/> 
</DiagnosisCodes></Account></Accounts>
```

Here is what I want it to look like:

```
> "    <Accounts>
>     <Account healthAccountRecord="100"
>       <DiagnosisCodes>
>         <DiagnosisCode code="1" />
>         <DiagnosisCode code="2" />    
>         <DiagnosisCode code="3" />   
>      </DiagnosisCodes>    </Account>
>     <Account healthAccountRecord="200"
>       <DiagnosisCodes>
>         <DiagnosisCode code="3" />
>         <DiagnosisCode code="4" />     
>       </DiagnosisCodes>   <Accounts>
> 
> "
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ab448/1

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @tb1 TABLE (id int);
insert into @tb1 values(100),(200);

DECLARE @tb2 table (id int, col2 int);
insert into @tb2 values(100,1),(100,2),(100,3),(200,3),(200,4);

SELECT 
  t.id as [@healthAccountRecord]
,(
  SELECT t2.col2 as [DiagnosisCode/@code]     
  FROM @tb2 as t2 
  WHERE t.id = t2.id    
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('DiagnosisCodes')
)
 FROM @tb1 as t
 FOR XML PATH('Account'), ROOT ('Accounts')
```

> Output

```
<Accounts>
  <Account healthAccountRecord="100">
    <DiagnosisCodes>
      <DiagnosisCode code="1" />
      <DiagnosisCode code="2" />
      <DiagnosisCode code="3" />
    </DiagnosisCodes>
  </Account>
  <Account healthAccountRecord="200">
    <DiagnosisCodes>
      <DiagnosisCode code="3" />
      <DiagnosisCode code="4" />
    </DiagnosisCodes>
  </Account>
</Accounts>
```

Comment: @JeffWeinberg, Good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. 
Please mark it as answered. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). 
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted"

Comment: Done..Thanks again!!